# Perform signature verification tasks on a server inappbilling android

Tags: android

I would like to implement inappbilling in android,for that we would like to perform signature verification on our server.Could anyone please let me know the process that we need to follow to verify signature in Java.I would also like to get test and production urls that our server will hit to verify signature.

Answer (score 7):

The process is exactly the same as in Android. You have to send the signed data and the signature to your server, and preform the verification there. If you were using servlets for example, you could perform a POST from Android, and the get the `signature` and `signedData` request parameters in your servlet. Then use the `Signature` class and your public key to verify. The IAB response also includes a nonce (randomly generated number), and in order to be able verify this too, you need to generate the nonce on your server as well. In short:

1. Android client requests a nonce from server
2. Server generates and saves nonce to DB, then returns it to client
3. Android client uses nonce to send IAB request
4. Android client sends IAB response (signature and signedData) to server
5. Server verifies signature. If not valid, return error.
6. If valid, extract nonce and check that it is one server has generated.
7. Server returns OK and any associated content (if you bought a movie, etc.)
8. Clients accepts transaction and enables features/gets content, etc.

There are no test or production URLs, you have to send the data from your Android app.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay for the quick detailed response.The only thing that i couldnot understand is how can the server verify that the signature send by the client is valid or not.Could you please give more explanation on that.Just like in iphone we will be hitting some sandbox url for testing and live url for production to test the signature ,do we have any such url that google provides which helps the server to verify the signature

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how the whole system works. The order data is signed by the Android Market/Google Play servers using aprivate key generated for a specific developer (you). Your app receives the signed data and can verify the signature in place using the corresponding public key or send it for verification to _your_ server. The process is essentially the same, with the benefit of a server being that you can keep your verification code secure. There is no online verification provided by Google, and thus no sandbox/production URLs for you to use.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Nikolay Basically I have an app where I would like to offer a subscription option for disabling ads. At which point in the process would I be using this server side verification?